# Handling different DbType Enums in Database-Agnostic architecture, how?

Tags: .net, vb.net, design-patterns, ado.net

Here's my current set-up:

```
Public Interface IDatabase
   Function CreateParameter(name as String, dbType as <dbTypeEnumeration>)
End Interface

Public Class OracleDatabaseRepository
    Implements IDatabase
    Public Function CreateParameter(ByVal name As String, ByVal dbtype As <dbTypeEnumeration>) As Object
    End Function
End Class

Public Class SQLServerRepository
    Implements IDatabase
    Public Function CreateParameter(ByVal name As String, ByVal dbtype As <dbTypeEnumeration>) As Object
    End Function
End Class

Public Class DatabaseService
    Private _rep As IDatabase
    Sub New(ByRef rep As IDatabase)
        _rep = rep
    End Sub
    Public Function CreateParameter(ByVal name As String, ByRef dbtype As <dbTypeEnumeration>) As Object
       _rep.CreateParameter(name, dbtype)
    End Function
End Class
```

The problem here is what exactly is dbTypeEnumeration. In the example above, it's simply a placeholder to what my problem is. Since we use both Oracle and SQL Server databases, the DbTypes are different depending on the database being used. For Oracle, the OracleClient object has its own OracleDbType enumeration with types. SQL Server also has its own enumeration.

My question is: is it possible to show those database-specific enumerations depending on which repository is injected into the DatabaseService constructor? If not, what's the best way to go about this? I want to separate the two databases, share logic, and allow for future development, ala the interface as a code contract for that development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repository implementation correctness asside, I'd change the level of `DbType` abstraction.

This `interface` is db agnostic.

```
Public Interface IDatabase
    Function CreateParameter(ByVal name As String, ByVal type As Type) As Object
End Interface
```

The db constrained implementation should be in your concrete `Repository` itself. How else would you want to keep it generic but still differ between the two types?

```
Public Class SqlServerRepo : Implements IDatabase

    Private Shared typeLookup As Dictionary(Of Type, Data.SqlDbType) = New Dictionary(Of Type, SqlDbType)

    Shared Sub New()
       (...Fill the dict according to your specification ...)
    End Sub

    Public Function CreateParameter(name As String, type As Type) As Object Implements IDatabase.CreateParameter
        Dim concreteDbType = typeLookup(type)
        (.. your parameter creation here ..)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class OracleServerRepo : Implements IDatabase

    Private Shared typeLookup As Dictionary(Of Type, OracleType) = New Dictionary(Of Type, OracleType)

    Shared Sub New()
        (...Fill the dict according to your specification ...)
    End Sub

    Public Function CreateParameter(name As String, type As Type) As Object Implements IDatabase.CreateParameter
        Dim concreteDbType = typeLookup(type)
         (.. your parameter creation here ..)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: This was my initial thought, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't some way I could use the service class.

Comment: There's the `System.Data.DBType` type but it just shares the common types between oracle and sql server - a specific type lookup would be more appropriate solution I suppose.

Comment: If I weren't going to use a Service class... I could just use the type as the Enumeration without having to use the Dictionary. The point is to inject the dependency into the Service class' constructor, then use the CreateParameter function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Although your classes have the word Repository in them they are not really following the Repository Design Pattern.  Take a look at this [MSDN detailed description of the Repository Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).  The Repository should return entities/objects that represent the application domain and not database specific information (i.e. dbType).  The Repository encapsulates the user from the database details and would handle converting the DB types to the appropriate .NET type.